# Query a button with specific text

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a (Jest) test to determine if a button exists:

```
it('renders a signup button', () => {
  expect(sut.getByText('Sign up for free')).toBeDefined()
})
```

This test because there is both a button AND heading with "Sign up for free" text in the component.

[image: Screenshot showing both a heading and button with "Sign up for free" text]

A `testid` could be added to the button, but I'd prefer to follow the **react-testing-library** principle of simulating user behaviour.

I feel it's legitimate a user would want to "click the button labelled 'Sign up for free'". In this situation, specifying the type of HTML element makes sense as a `<button />` is a distinctive element to the user, as opposed to be `<h2 />` vs `<h3 />`.

**How can I query for a button element labelled "Sign up for free"? For example can `getByText()` be further limited by a query selector?**

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm surprised no one here gives the most idiomatic answer yet. You can use [`getByRole()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole) and pass an [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/). The accessible name is the text of the button or the value of `aria-label` attribute.

It can be used to query a specific element if multiple elements with the same role are presented on the screen.

#### [Text button](https://testing-playground.com/gist/d1fccaab4701aa40142da6467eedbb36/f9f79b9a4a866756bcfda75fdbb1d175400d6e46)

```html
<button>Text Button</button>
```

```js
screen.getByRole('button', {
  name: /text button/i
})
```

#### [Icon button](https://testing-playground.com/gist/d1fccaab4701aa40142da6467eedbb36/a9af800216c328deb4f9cb60531cfd40e64ebc76)

```html
<button aria-label='edit'>
  <edit-icon />
</button>
```

```js
screen.getByRole('button', {
  name: /edit/i
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The `name` property didn't exist in my version of React Testing Library so I had to update the package. Just in case others come across the same problem.

Comment: [Here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) is current documentation which explains why `getByRole` is the most idiomatic. The Testing Library philosophy is to emulate actual usage as much as possible. Using [accessibility tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Accessibility_tree) objects emulates both visual/mouse users as well as those who use assistive technology such as screen readers.

Answer (score 38):

You can pass options to your query to change its default behavior:

```
getByText('Sign up for free', { selector: 'button' })
```

You can find the full documentation [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#queries)

Answer (score 16):

You can do it like this:

```
getByText('Sign up for free').closest('button')
```

You can read more about `closest` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: This will still find multiple elements, failing in `react-testing-library` >= 7.0. I only want to select a single element.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns multiple html elements, you can also use:

```
const elements = getAllByText('Sign up for free');
```

This will return an array of elements that match the query. Then if you know which element you need, you can access like this:`nodes[1]`

You can add the word 'All' to the different selectors to get an array of all matching queries (getAllByRole, queryAllByText, etc.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Also... if it is necessary, you can use `screen.queryBy*` without throw an error in the query operation

[Queries in react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries)