# Jest how to call a function from parent component that is passed as a prop to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const handleSetPage = () => {
    setPage(2);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {page === 1 && <ChildPage1 handleSetPage={handleSetPage} /> }
      {page === 2 && <ChildPage2  /> }
    </div>
  )
}

const ChildPage1 = ({handleSetPage}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={handleSetPage}>Next page</button>
  )
}


it('Continues to next page on button click', () =>  {
  render(<CreateDuty />);
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Next page'));
  expect('Page 2 text').toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Im trying to test that the pages change when button is clicked, but in the test handleSetPage() isnt being called.

How do I pass/wrap/mock the function so it gets called?

Comment: Do you have any error messages? And does it work if you [wait while asserting](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance) that page 2 is in the document?

Comment: Or if you wrap the fireEvent.click in a [act](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#act) method?

Comment: @A_A Neither work. It doesnt seem to call the function, as I put a console.log in it. It worked before when it was all in the same component, but after I broke it down to separate components for the pages, the test doesnt work anymore. Edit: The error is just that its unable to find the element.

Comment: Does this help you to find the element? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408178/query-a-button-with-specific-text

Answer (score 0):

First of all user events are async, which means you need to wrap your test function in an async function and `await` the user events.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

const Parent = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const handleSetPage = () => {
        setPage(2);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {page === 1 && <ChildPage1 handleSetPage={handleSetPage} />}
            {page === 2 && <ChildPage2 />}
        </div>
    )
}

const ChildPage1 = ({ handleSetPage }) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={handleSetPage}>Next page</button>
    )
}

const ChildPage2 = () => {
    return (
        <div>Page 2 text</div>
    )
}

it('Continues to next page on button click', async () => {
    render(<Parent />);
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    userEvent.click(button);
    const page2Text = await screen.findByText('Page 2 text');
    expect(page2Text).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

second, you need to find the element that you looking for and expect it. If you expect a string you will get this error:

```bash
received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has type:  string
Received has value: "Page 2 text"
```

in this example, I get the button by role because there is only one button on the screen. In real-world examples, you can give `id`'s to components that you want to test and use that id to get the component you want.